# Conexión a MySQL con c#

Tags: c#, mysql

tengo un problema al intentar conectarme a una base de datos, les explico, tengo un proyecto en Visual Studio 2019, el tipo de proyecto es una aplicación web asp.net (net.framework) y el lenguaje que utilizo es C#, para lograr esto hice lo siguiente:

- Agregué la referencia MySql.Data
  [image: muestra]
- Agregué las librerías: **using MySql.Data; using MySql.Data.MySqlClient; using   System.Data.SqlClient;**
- Ya tengo conexión con la base da datos y visual studio
  [image: conexión]

- El código que tengo es el siguiente:

  ```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Web;
  using System.Web.UI;
  using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
  using System.Security.Cryptography;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Web.Services.Description;
  using MySql.Data;
  using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
  using System.Data.SqlClient;

  namespace Facturacion
  {
    public partial class agent2 : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       //Es una variable de tipo bool para identificar si la página ha sido cargada por primera vez o es una recarga.
       if (!IsPostBack)
       {
           //conexion a mysql
           SqlConnection sqlConexion = new SqlConnection("Server=192.156.10.1; Database=prueba; user=root; password=Nl876#;");
           try
           {
               sqlConexion.Open();
               conexion.Text = "Conectados!!";
               sqlConexion.Close();
           }
           catch (System.Exception ex)
           {
               conexion.Text = ex.Message;
           }

         }
      }
    }
  }
  ```
- Pero al momento de ejecutarlo me arroja el siguiente error:
  **Conexión:** A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Agradecería mucho que me puedan orientar, apenas estoy empezando a usar c#, de antemano gracias.

Comment: El error habla sobre `SQL Server` pero has puesto la etiqueta de MySQL ¿? ¿Qué manejador es en definitiva? Cada uno tiene cadenas de conexión distintas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba la conexión de esta forma:

```
MySqlConnection sqlConexion = new MySqlConnection("Server=192.156.10.1; Database=prueba; user=root; password=Nl876#;");
```

Comment: Hola Antonio S.F. ¡muchas gracias! si fue por eso, perdona es que ando aprendiendo, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Estas utilizando un manejador para SQLServer mediante la librería System.Data.SqlClient, para conectarte a MySQL debes utilizar MySql.Data.MySqlClient, de este modo debería funcionarte:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Services.Description;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;


namespace Facturacion
{
  public partial class agent2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     //Es una variable de tipo bool para identificar si la página ha sido cargada por primera vez o es una recarga.
     if (!IsPostBack)
     {
         //conexion a mysql
         MySqlConnection sqlConexion = new MySqlConnection("datasource=192.156.10.1 ;port=3306(o tu puerto definido para MySQL);username=root;password=Nl876#;database=prueba;");
         try
         {
             sqlConexion.Open();
             conexion.Text = "Conectados!!";
             sqlConexion.Close();
         }
         catch (System.Exception ex)
         {
             conexion.Text = ex.Message;
         }

       }
    }
  }
}
```